# iOS4 data protection in MonoTouch?

Tags: ios4, xamarin.ios

my application downloads files and stores them in the personal folder. I would like to apply iOS4's data encryption but cannot find  equivalants to NSData's write methods which allow protecting files.

Is it in MT? Or are all files protected automatically?

René

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the NSData.Save (string file, NSDataWritingOptions options, out NSError error) API

And make sure that you pass the NSDataWritingOptions.FileProtectionComplete as the options argument.

Comment: Could it be that it just does NOTHING on the simulator? I can access and read the file content and it is not encrypted/protected.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [MonoTouch docs](http://go-mono.org/docs/index.aspx?link=C%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.NSData%28MonoTouch.Foundation.NSCoder%29), the [MonoTouch rosetta stone](http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html) description of NSData and the Apple docs section on [*Working with Protected Files*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html) the NSData._Save method is what you're looking for in MonoTouch.